# Change the color of the browser preview with Ctrl + Tab

Tags: firefox

When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Firefox, the browser preview window does come up but the selected tab is not highlighted such that it be clearly visible and is very difficult to spot. I am using Ubuntu 16. All the images in `/usr/share/unity/icons` are svg files. Which one of the files should I change to get the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> highlight changed in Firefox?